# Efficient list of unique strings C#

Tags: c#, unique-values

What is the most efficient way to store a list of strings ignoring any duplicates?
I was thinking a dictionary may be best inserting strings by writing dict[str] = false; and enumerating through the keys as a list. Is that a good solution?

Answer (score 122):

If you are using .NET 3.5, the [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) should work for you.

> The HashSet<(Of <(T>)>) class provides
>   high performance set operations. A set
>   is a collection that contains no
>   duplicate elements, and whose elements
>   are in no particular order.

Comment: But a `HashSet` will lose the order of items. A feature a `List` provides.

Comment: Additional: There is also SortedSet<T> which is a convenient sorted HashSet.

Comment: Also note that HashSet cannot be accessed through indice, only through an enumerator as oppose to a List.

Answer (score 33):

You can look to do something like this

```
var hash = new HashSet<string>();
var collectionWithDup = new []{"one","one","two","one","two","zero"}; 

// No need to check for duplicates as the Add method
// will only add it if it doesn't exist already
foreach (var str in collectionWithDup)
    hash.Add(str);
```

Comment: You don't need the Contains check with a HashSet. You can just call the Add method directly and it will return true or false depending on whether or not the item already exists.

Comment: Answer should be edited to remove the call to redundant Contains. This all you need for the above example to work: 
var collectionWithDup = new[] { "one", "one", "two", "one", "two", "zero" };
var uniqueValues = new HashSet<string>(collectionWithDup);

Answer (score 15):

I'm not sure if this counts as a good answer, but when faced with the need for a unique set that maintains insertion order, I compromised with a HashSet and a List side-by-side.  In this case, whenever you add to the set, do the following:

```
if(hashSet.Add(item))
    orderList.Add(item);
```

When removing items, make sure to remove them from both.  Thus, as long as you can be sure that nothing else added items to the list, you'll have an insertion-ordered unique set!

Answer (score 15):

You could also use Linq as in:

```
using System.Linq;

var items = new List<string>() { "one", "one", "two", "one", "two", "zero" };

List<string> distinctItems = items.Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: The official documentation states that "_the `Distinct<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>)` method returns an **unordered** sequence that contains no duplicate values_" (emphasis added by me). So you can't use Distinct if the order of the values is important.

Answer (score 10):

Use HashSet, no need to check .Contains() , just add your items in list and if its duplicate it will not add it.

```
   HashSet<int> uniqueList = new HashSet<int>();
   uniqueList.Add(1); // List has values 1
   uniqueList.Add(2);  // List has values 1,2
   uniqueList.Add(1);  // List has values 1,2
   Console.WriteLine(uniqueList.Count); // it will return 2
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not part of the the system namespace but have used the  Iesi.Collections from http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/sets.aspx with NHibernate. It has support for hashed set along with sorted set, dictionary set, and so on. Since it has been used with NHibernate it has been used extensively and very stable. This also does not require .Net 3.5

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution without using the `HashSet`.

```
var items = new List<string>() { "one", "one", "two", "one", "two", "zero" };
var uniqueItems = items.Where((item, index) => items.IndexOf(item) == index);
```

It was adopted from this thread: [javascript - Unique values in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14438954/469829)

Test:

```
using FluentAssertions;

uniqueItems.Count().Should().Be(3);
uniqueItems.Should().BeEquivalentTo("one", "two", "zero");
```

Performance test for `List`, `HashSet` and `SortedSet`. 1 million iterations:

```
List: 564 ms
HashSet: 487 ms
SortedSet: 1932 ms
```

[Test source code (gist)](https://gist.github.com/alexeysolonets/e0b64c5b4f9496596f894f4efacb7f4f)