# Get all unique values in a JavaScript array (remove duplicates)

Tags: javascript, unique, arrays

I have an array of numbers that I need to make sure are unique. I found the code snippet below on the internet and it works great until the array has a zero in it. I found [this other script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890203) here on Stack Overflow that looks almost exactly like it, but it doesn't fail.

So for the sake of helping me learn, can someone help me determine where the prototype script is going wrong?

```
Array.prototype.getUnique = function() {
 var o = {}, a = [], i, e;
 for (i = 0; e = this[i]; i++) {o[e] = 1};
 for (e in o) {a.push (e)};
 return a;
}
```

Comment: @hippietrail That older question is about finding and returning only the duplicates (I was confused too!). My question is more about why this function fails when an array has a zero in it.

Comment: For future readers, when start finding that you have to algorithmically modify the contents of your data structure all the time, (order them, remove repeating elements, etc.) or search for elements inside it at every iteration, it's safe to assume that you're using the wrong data structure in the first place and start using one that is more appropriate for the task at hand (in this case a hash set instead of array).

Comment: I copied the code from somewhere else, a loooong time ago... but it seems pretty straight-forward: `o` = `object`, `a` = `array`, `i` = `index` and `e` = umm, something :P

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get unique values in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246758/how-to-get-unique-values-in-an-array)

Comment: Just wanted to point out, a lot of people have suggested using JavaScript Set as a solution, proceed with caution because it is not supported in Internet Explorer. If you have to support IE, then use a polyfill.

Comment: For those who want to return an array of objects with all properties unique by key: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125920/how-to-get-distinct-values-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript/58429784#58429784

Comment: using the ramda R.uniq(list) solves this. https://ramdajs.com/docs/#uniq

Comment: my favorite way is `let uniqueArray = [...new Set(originalArray)];` 

Comment: @LukasLiesis I'm not sure the "" is appropriate https://javascript.plainenglish.io/es5-vs-es6-performance-comparisons-c3606a241633. Please folks, stop confusing short and fast.

Comment: @user6316468 Please note the highlight of the code part. Rocket emoji has nothing to do with sample code. Sorry to confuse though.

Comment: Related: [Showing unique characters in a string only once](/q/13868043/4642212).

Comment: Please avoid using since character variables in code you expect others to read. It will also stop you having to write `e = umm, something`,

Comment: The fact that this still isn't in JS core ... mind blowing

Comment: @maxpleaner What do you mean? We have [`Set`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). Even then, there is a [proposal for a dedicated Array method](//github.com/tc39/proposal-array-unique).

Answer (score 4593, accepted):

With *JavaScript 1.6* / *ECMAScript 5* you can use the native [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method of an Array in the following way to get an array with unique values:

```js
function onlyUnique(value, index, array) {
  return array.indexOf(value) === index;
}

// usage example:
var a = ['a', 1, 'a', 2, '1'];
var unique = a.filter(onlyUnique);

console.log(unique); // ['a', 1, 2, '1']
```

The native method `filter` will loop through the array and leave only those entries that pass the given callback function `onlyUnique`.

`onlyUnique` checks, if the given value is the first occurring. If not, it must be a duplicate and will not be copied.

This solution works without any extra library like jQuery or prototype.js.

It works for arrays with mixed value types too.

For old Browsers (<ie9), that do not support the native methods `filter` and `indexOf` you can find work arounds in the MDN documentation for [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

If you want to keep the last occurrence of a value, simply replace `indexOf` with `lastIndexOf`.

With ES6 this can be shorten to:

```js
// usage example:
var myArray = ['a', 1, 'a', 2, '1'];
var unique = myArray.filter((value, index, array) => array.indexOf(value) === index);

console.log(unique); // unique is ['a', 1, 2, '1']
```

Thanks to [Camilo Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/124119/camilo-martin) for hint in comment.

ES6 has a native object [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to store unique values. To get an array with unique values you could now do this:

```js
var myArray = ['a', 1, 'a', 2, '1'];

let unique = [...new Set(myArray)];

console.log(unique); // unique is ['a', 1, 2, '1']
```

The constructor of `Set` takes an iterable object, like an Array, and the spread operator `...` transform the set back into an Array. Thanks to [Lukas Liese](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1737158/lukas-liesis) for hint in comment.

Comment: This solution will run much slower, unfortunately. You're looping twice, once with filter and once with index of

Comment: In modern JS: `.filter((v,i,a)=>a.indexOf(v)==i)` (fat arrow notation).

Comment: `let unique_values = [...new Set(random_array)];` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Comment: Performance wise, set is the way to go https://medium.com/@jakubsynowiec/unique-array-values-in-javascript-7c932682766c
It's only downside IMO is that it does not make the programmers intent clear. I mean once you know what it does, you get it, but it's nowhere near as clear as something like `myArray.unique()`

Comment: Why is `[...` ... `]` necessary? `new Set(myArray)` on its own seems to have the same behaviour

Comment: ...in fact using the square brackets seems to create an array of size 1 containing the set

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/array-uniq uses the `Set` approach

Comment: Does anyone understand how to type the 'self' parameter in the function if using typescript?

Comment: Lest any newcomer be scared away by the performance implications, consider "much slower" may very well be nanoseconds. If your array is relatively small (hundreds or less), using the nice concise one off version like this is good for reasons outside of performance, i.e. readability and maintainability. 
But the set version is quite nice and concise.

Comment: Late to the party, but `let unique_values = Array.from(new Set(random_array));` is IMO easier to read.

Comment: Comparing performance of .filter+indexOf and the Set-approach in Chrome 100 revealed that for  an array with numbers and length 0 to 120 the filter-approach is even faster. With array length 200 the filter-approach takes 50% more time than with a Set (6 vs. 9 microseconds). For 5000 elements the filter operation takes over 3 milliseconds while Set still copes with my example in 173 microseconds. So "much slower", really depends on the use case.
If someone is interested I can post the data as a separate Q&A.

Comment: Honestly? neither method is somthing I'd rely on. If you have an array with objects for example, then it will not get rid of duplicates (because every object ref. is unique).

You are going to have to loop the array once per lookup anyway (unless you have sorted all your duplicates to align one after another, in which case you only need to compare with the current index minus 1), so I think a more robust approach would be to simply filter out the duplicate values in a for loop when you're building your array.

Just makes more resource sense than to build another array for filtering.

Comment: i wish someone would show how to use the `set` method in an array prototype extender function.

Comment: @NicoWheat use the array version of whatever you have in `value`, e.g.:
`function onlyUnique(value: string | number, index: number, self: (string | number)[])`

Comment: const cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "BMW"];
for(var i=0;i<cars.length;i++){
if(cars[i] != cars[i+1]){
alert(cars[i]);
}
}

Comment: `self` is not working.

Comment: error, guess new things are not backward compatible: {
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: self.indexOf is not a function",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 13,
  "colno": 15
}

Comment: `[...new Set(myArray)];` is cool 

Comment: The only answer is the set. Everything else would be super slow for a decently sized array!

Comment: right, you should not use the `indexOf` method, because that's O(n²), so if your n happens to be 2000, you are looking at 4 million iterations potentially. You probably don't want that to happen in the browser to make the UI sluggish

Comment: @Christian How do you measure the timing? with console.time()?

Comment: Sorry, @Cemstrian, it's over a year ago and I don't have the code available any more.

Answer (score 1845):

**Updated answer for ES6/ES2015**: Using the [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and [the spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) (thanks [le-m](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1647737/le-m)), the single line solution is:

```
let uniqueItems = [...new Set(items)]
```

Which returns

```
[4, 5, 6, 3, 2, 23, 1]
```

Comment: Notice, that inner array wouldn't work `Array.from(new Set([[1,2],[1,2],[1,2,3]]))`

Comment: Please note that if you use the `Set` and add objects instead of primitive values it will contain unique *references* to the objects.  Thus the set `s` in `let s = new Set([{Foo:"Bar"}, {Foo:"Bar"}]);` will return this: `Set { { Foo: 'Bar' }, { Foo: 'Bar' } }` which is a `Set` with unique object references to objects that contain the same values. If you write `let o = {Foo:"Bar"};` and then create a set with two *references* like so: `let s2 = new Set([o,o]);`, then s2 will be `Set { { Foo: 'Bar' } }`

Comment: In case anyone was wondering, this works well for strings too, e.g. 
[...new Set(["apple","apple","orange"])] results in ['apple', 'orange'] . Great!

Comment: In Typescript, use `Array.from( new Set( items ) )`

Comment: Does using Set preserve the item order?

Answer (score 356):

I split all answers to 4 possible solutions:

1. Use object `{ }` to prevent duplicates
2. Use helper array `[ ]`
3. Use `filter + indexOf`
4. Bonus! ES6 [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/Set) constructor.

Here's sample codes found in answers:

## Use object `{ }` to prevent duplicates

```
function uniqueArray1( ar ) {
  var j = {};

  ar.forEach( function(v) {
    j[v+ '::' + typeof v] = v;
  });

  return Object.keys(j).map(function(v){
    return j[v];
  });
}
```

## Use helper array `[ ]`

```
function uniqueArray2(arr) {
    var a = [];
    for (var i=0, l=arr.length; i<l; i++)
        if (a.indexOf(arr[i]) === -1 && arr[i] !== '')
            a.push(arr[i]);
    return a;
}
```

## Use `filter + indexOf`

```
function uniqueArray3(a) {
  function onlyUnique(value, index, self) { 
      return self.indexOf(value) === index;
  }
  
  // usage
  var unique = a.filter( onlyUnique ); // returns ['a', 1, 2, '1']
  
  return unique;
}
```

## Use **ES6** `[...new Set(a)]`

```
function uniqueArray4(a) {
  return [...new Set(a)];
}
```

And I wondered which one is faster. I've made [sample Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-Vr4dD0GE0dv1PN9Ng6SyNwn8A407L1zw9uE1cBMwjQ/edit#gid=0) to test functions. Note: ECMA 6 is not avaliable in Google Sheets, so I can't test it.

Here's the result of tests:
[image]

I expected to see that code using object `{ }` will win because it uses hash. So I'm glad that tests showed the best results for this algorithm in Chrome and IE. Thanks to @rab for [the code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29327129/5372400).

### Update 2020

Google Script enabled ES6 Engine. Now I tested the last code with `Set` and it appeared faster than the object method.

Comment: Makrov, so the `uniqueItems = [...new Set(items)]` appears to be the fastest and the most succinct of all the approaches?

Comment: Your solution only handles primitives, it won't work with objects, you'd need to JSON.stringify the v in the hash

Comment: you are GREAT for making this time test comparison, thanks, I tested now with an Array with hundreds of thousands of entries and indeed `uniqueItems = [...new Set(items)]` seems the fastest

Comment: "Object.keys(j).map ..." could be changed to use `Object.values(j);`

Answer (score 164):

You can also use [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/).

```js
console.log(_.uniq([1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4]));
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

which will return:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Please do this folks. Don't jack something onto to the Array prototype. Please.

Comment: @JacobDalton Please don't do this. There's no need to add an extra library just for a small job that can be done with `array = [...new Set(array)]`

Comment: @JacobDalton why not? Is there a downside to "jacking something" onto the array?

Comment: If you want to find unique _objects_ using object equality semantics, Lodash offers `_.uniqWith(arrayOfObjects, _.isEqual)`. `_.uniqWith([{a: 2}, {b: 3}, {a: 2}], _.isEqual)` gives `[{a: 2}, {b: 3}]`.

Comment: This is a good solution overall, but surely the best solution if _you already have a library to do that in your dependencies._ This answer inspired me to look up something among my dependencies and, lo and behold, we already use lodash, which already has an `uniq()` funciton. So, even if it is not the same lib, thanks for the heads-up!

Answer (score 150):

## One Liner, Pure JavaScript

**With ES6 syntax**

`list = list.filter((x, i, a) => a.indexOf(x) == i)`

```
x --> item in array
i --> index of item
a --> array reference, (in this case "list")
```

[image]

**With ES5 syntax**

```
list = list.filter(function (x, i, a) { 
    return a.indexOf(x) == i; 
});
```

**Browser Compatibility**: IE9+

Answer (score 105):

Remove duplicates using [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

`Array` with duplicates

```js
const withDuplicates = [2, 2, 5, 5, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3];
```

Get a new array without duplicates by using Set

```js
const withoutDuplicates = Array.from(new Set(withDuplicates));
```

A shorter version

```js
const withoutDuplicates = [...new Set(withDuplicates)];
```

Result: `[2, 5, 1, 3]`

Comment: Completely duplicated answer for ones other ones given years before this one.

Answer (score 76):

Many of the answers here may not be useful to beginners. If de-duping an array is difficult, will they really know about the prototype chain, or even jQuery?

In modern browsers, a clean and simple solution is to store data in a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), which is designed to be a list of unique values.

```js
const cars = ['Volvo', 'Jeep', 'Volvo', 'Lincoln', 'Lincoln', 'Ford'];
const uniqueCars = Array.from(new Set(cars));
console.log(uniqueCars);
```

The `Array.from` is useful to convert the Set back to an Array so that you have easy access to all of the awesome methods (features) that arrays have. There are also [other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069828/how-to-convert-set-to-array) of doing the same thing. But you may not need `Array.from` at all, as Sets have plenty of useful features like [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/forEach).

If you need to support old Internet Explorer, and thus cannot use Set, then a simple technique is to copy items over to a new array while checking beforehand if they are already in the new array.

```
// Create a list of cars, with duplicates.
var cars = ['Volvo', 'Jeep', 'Volvo', 'Lincoln', 'Lincoln', 'Ford'];
// Create a list of unique cars, to put a car in if we haven't already.
var uniqueCars = [];

// Go through each car, one at a time.
cars.forEach(function (car) {
    // The code within the following block runs only if the
    // current car does NOT exist in the uniqueCars list
    // - a.k.a. prevent duplicates
    if (uniqueCars.indexOf(car) === -1) {
        // Since we now know we haven't seen this car before,
        // copy it to the end of the uniqueCars list.
        uniqueCars.push(car);
    }
});
```

To make this instantly reusable, let's put it in a function.

```
function deduplicate(data) {
    if (data.length > 0) {
        var result = [];

        data.forEach(function (elem) {
            if (result.indexOf(elem) === -1) {
                result.push(elem);
            }
        });

        return result;
    }
}
```

So to get rid of the duplicates, we would now do this.

```
var uniqueCars = deduplicate(cars);
```

The `deduplicate(cars)` part **becomes** the thing we named *result* when the function completes.

Just pass it the name of any array you like.

Comment: How would this work if I wanted the new array to not be uniques, but be an array of values that were duplicated? So using the above example, the array I'm looking for is `["volvo","lincoln"]`

Comment: @Jason I'd probably create a `Map` to store previously seen items and an array to store the duplicate items. Then loop through the `cars` array and check if the Map has the current item, if it does then push it to the duplicates array, if not then add it to the Map. I'd be happy to create a code example for you if you create a new question and we can continue the discussion there.

Comment: Just note that if the array is empty, the function does not return anything.

Comment: too bad you didn't show the `set` method as an extension of array.prototype

Comment: I deliberately did not show that. I consider it bad practice to modify `Array.prototype` and would strongly advise against doing so. Among other reasons, it can lead to future bugs if new methods are added to Array as part of the language. In fact, if your site is popular, it could even prevent new methods from being added to the language. That has actually happened. See: https://2ality.com/2022/03/naming-conflicts.html

Answer (score 69):

**Using ES6 *new Set***

```js
var array = [3,7,5,3,2,5,2,7];
var unique_array = [...new Set(array)];
console.log(unique_array);    // output = [3,7,5,2]
```

**Using *For Loop***

```js
var array = [3,7,5,3,2,5,2,7];

for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
    for(var j=i+1;j<array.length;j++) {
        if(array[i]===array[j]) {
            array.splice(j,1);
        }
    }
}
console.log(array); // output = [3,7,5,2]
```

Answer (score 53):

I have since found a nice method that uses jQuery

```
arr = $.grep(arr, function(v, k){
    return $.inArray(v ,arr) === k;
});
```

Note: This code was pulled from [Paul Irish's duck punching post](http://paulirish.com/2010/duck-punching-with-jquery/) - I forgot to give credit :P

Comment: A concise solution, but calling inArray is way less efficient than calling hasOwnProperty.

Comment: This is also O(N^2), right? Whereas the dictionary or hasOwnProperty approach would likely be O(N*logN).

Answer (score 51):

### Magic

```
a.filter( e => !(t[e]=e in t) )
```

**O(n)** performance - we assume your array is in `a` and `t={}`. Explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53453045/860099) (+[Jeppe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3717691/jeppe) impr.)

```js
let unique = (a,t={}) => a.filter(e=>!(t[e]=e in t));

// "stand-alone" version working with global t:
// a1.filter((t={},e=>!(t[e]=e in t)));

// Test data
let a1 = [5,6,0,4,9,2,3,5,0,3,4,1,5,4,9];
let a2 = [[2, 17], [2, 17], [2, 17], [1, 12], [5, 9], [1, 12], [6, 2], [1, 12]];
let a3 = ['Mike', 'Adam','Matt', 'Nancy', 'Adam', 'Jenny', 'Nancy', 'Carl'];

// Results
console.log(JSON.stringify( unique(a1) ))
console.log(JSON.stringify( unique(a2) ))
console.log(JSON.stringify( unique(a3) ))
```

Comment: this look so super cool, that without a solid explanation i fell you're gonna mine bitcoins when i run this

Comment: what i meant is that you should expand your answer with some explanation and commented deconstruction of it. don't expect people will find useful answers like this. (though it really looks cool a probably works)

Comment: Not magic, but is much like the "Set"-answers, using O(1) key-lookups in the dictionary. Do you need to increment the counters though? How about "e=>!(t[e]=e in t)". Nice answer though.

Comment: @Jeppe when I run your improvement then I experience [aha effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eureka_effect) (before I don't know that I can use `in` operator outside the other construction than `for` loop :P) - Thank you - I appreciate it and will give +2 to your other good answers.

Comment: Well, the solution is so great indeed
However it works well for tuples only
The examples below work incorrect:
`unique(['2', 2]) //  ['2'];`
`unique([[1, 7], [1, '7'], ['1', 7], ['1', '7']]) //  [1, 7]`
So be careful using this

Answer (score 37):

We can do this using ES6 sets:

```js
var duplicatesArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4];
var uniqueArray = [...new Set(duplicatesArray)];

console.log(uniqueArray); // [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Answer (score 36):

The simplest, and [fastest](https://jsbench.me/6qkt3h9ukg) (in Chrome) way of doing this:

```
Array.prototype.unique = function() {
    var a = [];
    for (var i=0, l=this.length; i<l; i++)
        if (a.indexOf(this[i]) === -1)
            a.push(this[i]);
    return a;
}
```

Simply goes through every item in the array, tests if that item is already in the list, and if it's not, pushes to the array that gets returned.

According to JSBench, this function is [the fastest of the ones I could find anywhere](https://jsbench.me/6qkt3h9ukg) - feel free to add your own though.

The non-prototype version:

```
function uniques(arr) {
    var a = [];
    for (var i=0, l=arr.length; i<l; i++)
        if (a.indexOf(arr[i]) === -1 && arr[i] !== '')
            a.push(arr[i]);
    return a;
}
```

### Sorting

When also needing to sort the array, the following is the fastest:

```
Array.prototype.sortUnique = function() {
    this.sort();
    var last_i;
    for (var i=0;i<this.length;i++)
        if ((last_i = this.lastIndexOf(this[i])) !== i)
            this.splice(i+1, last_i-i);
    return this;
}
```

or non-prototype:

```
function sortUnique(arr) {
    arr.sort();
    var last_i;
    for (var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        if ((last_i = arr.lastIndexOf(arr[i])) !== i)
            arr.splice(i+1, last_i-i);
    return arr;
}
```

This is also [faster than the above method](https://jsbench.me/6qkt3h9ukg) in most non-Chrome browsers.

Comment: On Linux, Chrome 55.0.2883 prefers your arr.unique() and swilliams' arrclone2.sortFilter() is slowest (78% slower).  However, Firefox 51.0.0 (with lots of addons) has swilliams as fastest (yet still slower by Ops/sec than any other Chrome result) with mottie's [jQuery $.grep(arr, jqFilter)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11455508/519360) being slowest (46% slower).  Your arr.uniq() was 30% slower.  I ran each test twice and got consistent results.  Rafael's [arr.getUnique()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1961068/519360) got second place in both browsers.

Comment: jsPerf is [buggy](https://github.com/jsperf/jsperf.com/issues/236) at the moment, so my edit to this test didn't commit everything, but it did result in adding two tests:  Cocco's [toUnique()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25082874/519360) beats Vamsi's [ES6 list.filter()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39272981/519360) on both browsers, beating swilliams' sortFilter() for #1 on FF (sortFilter was 16% slower) and beating your sorted testing (which was slower by 2%) for #3 on Chrome.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't caught that those tests were trivially small and don't really matter.  A comment to the accepted answer [describes that problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/unique-values-in-an-array/25082874#comment32934630_1961068) and offers a correction in a [revision](https://jsperf.com/unique-in-array/3) to the test, in which Rafael's code is easily the fastest and Joetje50's arr.unique code is 98% slower.  I've also made another revision as noted in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/unique-values-in-an-array/25082874#comment71331623_25082874).

Comment: Well, actually the algorithm you implemented in `unique` function has O(n^2) complexity while the one in `getUnique` is O(n). The first one may be faster on small data sets, but how can you argue with the maths :) You can make sure the latter one is faster if you run it on an array of, say, 1e5 unique items

Comment: also used by [lodash.uniq](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/86a852fe763935bb64c12589df5391fd7d3bb14d/.internal/baseUniq.js#L20) for `input_array.length < 200`, otherwise uses the `[...new Set(input_array)]` method. expressed as reducer: `input_array.reduce((c, v) => {if (!c.includes(v)) c.push(v); return c;}, [])`

Comment: `unique` shouldn't use `lastIndexOf`, as that causes O(n^2) performance. Instead, have `var last_value = null;`... `if (arr[i] !== last_value) { if (last_i !== null) arr.splice(last_i+1, i - last_i); last_i = i; last_value = arr[i]; }` - not tested, `i - last_i` might be off by 1.

Comment: how is this the fastest way? who in the world would upvote this answer?

Comment: @Gino To be honest, I'm still not that surprised it was the fastest out of the answers given at the time, because there were just some very inefficient answers. Just using an ES6 approach such as `filter`s or `Set`s is probably *much* more efficient nowadays.

Comment: @Joeytje50 but this is n^2

Answer (score 25):

```
["Defects", "Total", "Days", "City", "Defects"].reduce(function(prev, cur) {
  return (prev.indexOf(cur) < 0) ? prev.concat([cur]) : prev;
 }, []);

[0,1,2,0,3,2,1,5].reduce(function(prev, cur) {
  return (prev.indexOf(cur) < 0) ? prev.concat([cur]) : prev;
 }, []);
```

Comment: This worked very well with an array of objects!

`[].reduce((p, c) => (p.some((item) => c.id === item.id) ? p : p.concat(c)), [])`

Answer (score 25):

## Primitive values

### With [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) (Recommended)

```js
var array = ["FreePhoenix888", "FreePhoenix888", "konard", "FreePhoenix888"];

let set = [...new Set(array)];

console.log(set); // ["FreePhoenix888", "konard"]
```

### Without [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```js
function filterUniqueObjects(value, index, array) {
  return array.indexOf(value) === index;
}

// usage example:
var array = ["FreePhoenix888", "FreePhoenix888", "konard", "FreePhoenix888"];
var arrayOfUniqueItems = array.filter(filterUniqueObjects);

console.log(arrayOfUniqueItems); // ["FreePhoenix888", "konard"]
```

## Objects

This example shows how you can filter not just an array of primitive values but an array of objects. I have added comments to make it easier to understand what you can change there depending on your requirements.

```js
let array = [
  { name: '@deep-foundation/core', version: '0.0.2' },
  { name: '@deep-foundation/capacitor-device', version: '10.0.1' },
  { name: '@deep-foundation/capacitor-device', version: '10.0.2' },
];

// Of course you can inline this function as filter argument uniqueArray.filter((item, index, self) => self.findIndex(innerItem => innerItem.name === item.name) === index);
function filterUniqueObjects(value, index, self) {
  return (
    self.findIndex(
      // Modify this function as you desire. You may want to calculate uniqueness depending only on specific fields, not all
      (obj) => obj.name === value.name
    ) === index
  );
};

let uniqueArray = array
  .reverse() // If you want latest duplicates to remain
  .filter(filterUniqueObjects)
  .reverse(); // To get back to original order after first reverse

console.log(uniqueArray)
```

Answer (score 24):

This has been answered a lot, but it didn't address my particular need.

Many answers are like this:

```
a.filter((item, pos, self) => self.indexOf(item) === pos);
```

But this doesn't work for arrays of complex objects.

Say we have an array like this:

```
const a = [
 { age: 4, name: 'fluffy' },
 { age: 5, name: 'spot' },
 { age: 2, name: 'fluffy' },
 { age: 3, name: 'toby' },
];
```

If we want the objects with unique names, we should use `array.prototype.findIndex` instead of `array.prototype.indexOf`:

```
a.filter((item, pos, self) => self.findIndex(v => v.name === item.name) === pos);
```

Comment: Great solution, beware that a new array will return from a function. (it doesn't modify itself)

Comment: Works will with a complex array of objets

Comment: @EdgarQuintero only if the elements are actually the exact same object, so the array [ { a: 2 }, { a: 2 } ] won't work as many people might expect if you use the `indexOf` solution, but the `findIndex` solution might be useful

Answer (score 23):

After looking into all the **90+** answers here, I saw there is room for one more:

[Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) has a very handy second-parameter: *"fromIndex"*, so by using it, every iteration of the `filter` callback method will search the *array*, starting from `[current index] + 1` which **guarantees** not to include *currently* filtered item in the lookup and also saves time.

> Note - this solution does not retain the order, as it removed duplicated items from *left to right*, but it wins the `Set` trick if the *Array* is a collection of *Objects*.

```js
//                               
var list = [0,1,2,2,3,'a','b',4,5,2,'a']

console.log( 
  list.filter((v,i) => !list.includes(v,i+1))
)

// [0,1,3,"b",4,5,2,"a"]
```

#### Explanation:

For example, lets assume the `filter` function is currently iterating at index `2`) and the value at that index happens to be `2`. The section of the array that is then scanned for duplicates (`includes` method) is everything **after** index 2 (`i+1`):

```
                               
[0, 1, 2,   2 ,3 ,'a', 'b', 4, 5, 2, 'a']
          |---------------------------|
```

And since the currently filtered item's value `2` is included in the rest of the array, it will be filtered out, because of the leading exclamation mark which negates the filter rule.

---

#### If order is important, use this method:

```js
//                               
var list = [0,1,2,2,3,'a','b',4,5,2,'a']

console.log( 
  // Initialize with empty array and fill with non-duplicates
  list.reduce((acc, v) => (!acc.includes(v) && acc.push(v), acc), [])
)

// [0,1,2,3,"a","b",4,5]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this keeps the LAST instance of each value, not the first.
(which might be ok, but I think keeping the first is generally what's expected)

Comment: Although this is a nice optimization idea, I don't think people would want to use this since this's keeping the last item which basically mess up the array order.

Answer (score 22):

You can simlply use the built-in functions `Array.prototype.filter()` and `Array.prototype.indexOf()`

`array.filter((x, y) => array.indexOf(x) == y)`

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 6, 9];

var newarr = arr.filter((x, y) => arr.indexOf(x) == y);

console.log(newarr);
```

Answer (score 21):

This prototype `getUnique` is not totally correct, because if i have a Array like: `["1",1,2,3,4,1,"foo"]` it will return `["1","2","3","4"]` and `"1"` is string and `1` is a integer; they are different.

Here is a correct solution:

```
Array.prototype.unique = function(a){
    return function(){ return this.filter(a) }
}(function(a,b,c){ return c.indexOf(a,b+1) < 0 });
```

using:

```
var foo;
foo = ["1",1,2,3,4,1,"foo"];
foo.unique();
```

The above will produce `["1",2,3,4,1,"foo"]`.

Comment: Note that `$foo = 'bar'` is the PHP way of declaring variables. It will work in javascript, but will create an implicit global, and generally shouldn't be done.

Comment: @CamiloMartin sorry but you're wrong, $foo is global because the example is not in a closure and he's missing the var keyword. Nothing to do with the dollar http://jsfiddle.net/robaldred/L2MRb/

Comment: @Rob that's exactly what I'm saying, PHP people will think `$foo` is the way of declaring variables in javascript while actually `var foo` is.

Answer (score 18):

```
[...new Set(duplicates)]
```

> This is the simplest one and referenced from **[MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#Remove_duplicate_elements_from_the_array)**.

```
const numbers = [2,3,4,4,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,5,32,3,4,5]
console.log([...new Set(numbers)]) // [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 32]
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an [explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Identical to [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49725248/104380) which dates a year prior to this one

Answer (score 17):

That's because `0` is a falsy value in JavaScript.

`this[i]` will be falsy if the value of the array is 0 or any other falsy value.

Comment: Ahhhh, ok I see now... but would there be an easy fix to make it work?

Answer (score 17):

```
Array.prototype.getUnique = function() {
    var o = {}, a = []
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) o[this[i]] = 1
    for (var e in o) a.push(e)
    return a
}
```

Comment: I think this won't work if the array contains objects/arrays, and I'm not sure if it will preserve the type of scalars.

Comment: Yes, everything gets stringified.  That could be fixed by storing the original value in `o` instead of just a `1`, although equality comparison would still be stringwise (although, out of all the possible Javascript equalities, it doesn't seem too unreasonable).

Comment: The Array.prototype could be extended only with non enumerable methods .... Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype,"getUnique",{}) ...  but the idea of using a helper object is very nice

Answer (score 17):

Without extending Array.prototype (it is said to be a bad practice) or using jquery/underscore, you can simply `filter` the array.

By keeping last occurrence:

```
    function arrayLastUnique(array) {
        return array.filter(function (a, b, c) {
            // keeps last occurrence
            return c.indexOf(a, b + 1) < 0;
        });
    },
```

or first occurrence:

```
    function arrayFirstUnique(array) {
        return array.filter(function (a, b, c) {
            // keeps first occurrence
            return c.indexOf(a) === b;
        });
    },
```

Well, it's only javascript ECMAScript 5+, which means only IE9+, but it's nice for a development in native HTML/JS (Windows Store App, Firefox OS, Sencha, Phonegap, Titanium, ...).

Comment: The fact that it's js 1.6 does not mean you can't use `filter`. At the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) they have an implementation for Internet Explorer, I mean, older browsers. Also: JS 1.6 refers only to Firefox's js engine, but the right thing to say it's that it is ECMAScript 5.

Answer (score 14):

Now using sets you can remove duplicates and convert them back to the array.

```js
var names = ["Mike","Matt","Nancy", "Matt","Adam","Jenny","Nancy","Carl"];

console.log([...new Set(names)])
```

Another solution is to use sort & filter

```js
var names = ["Mike","Matt","Nancy", "Matt","Adam","Jenny","Nancy","Carl"];
var namesSorted = names.sort();
const result = namesSorted.filter((e, i) => namesSorted[i] != namesSorted[i+1]);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 13):

If you're using Prototype framework there is no need to do 'for' loops, you can use http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/language/Array/prototype/uniq/ like this:

```
var a = Array.uniq();
```

Which will produce a duplicate array with no duplicates. I came across your question searching a method to count distinct array records so after `uniq()` I used  `size()` and there was my simple result.
p.s. Sorry if i mistyped something

edit: if you want to escape undefined records you may want to add `compact()` before, like this:

```
var a = Array.compact().uniq();
```

Comment: because i found a better answer, i think about topics are for all people not just for the one who asked

Comment: Thanks for time machine yet iirc around 15 years ago JS community had debate and result is - do not extend prototype cause of side effects and cause you pollute all JS arrays this way.

Answer (score 12):

I had a slightly different problem where I needed to remove objects with duplicate id properties from an array. this worked.

```js
let objArr = [{
  id: '123'
}, {
  id: '123'
}, {
  id: '456'
}];

objArr = objArr.reduce((acc, cur) => [
  ...acc.filter((obj) => obj.id !== cur.id), cur
], []);

console.log(objArr);
```

Answer (score 10):

If you're okay with extra dependencies, or you already have one of the libraries in your codebase, you can remove duplicates from an array in place using LoDash (or Underscore).

**Usage**

If you don't have it in your codebase already, install it using npm:

```
npm install lodash
```

Then use it as follows:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
let idArray = _.uniq ([
    1,
    2,
    3,
    3,
    3
]);
console.dir(idArray);
```

**Out:**

```
[ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

Comment: You can also use lodash to remove objects with duplicate properties from an array: `_.uniqWith(objectArray, _.isEqual)`.

Answer (score 9):

In ES6/Later

Get Only Unique Values

```
  let a = [
           { id: 1, name: "usman" },
           { id: 2, name: "zia" },
           { id: 3, name: "usman" },
          ];
const unique = [...new Set(a.map((item) => item.name))];
console.log(unique); // ["usman", "zia"]
```

**Get Unique Objects**

```
const myObjArray = [
                       { id: 1, name: "usman" },
                       { id: 2, name: "zia" },
                       { id: 3, name: "usman" },
                   ];
// Creates an array of objects with unique "name" property values.
let uniqueObjArray = [
  ...new Map(myObjArray.map((item) => [item["name"], item])).values(),
];

console.log("uniqueObjArray", uniqueObjArray);
```

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure why Gabriel Silveira wrote the function that way but a simpler form that works for me just as well and without the minification is:

```
Array.prototype.unique = function() {
  return this.filter(function(value, index, array) {
    return array.indexOf(value, index + 1) < 0;
  });
};
```

or in CoffeeScript:

```
Array.prototype.unique = ->
  this.filter( (value, index, array) ->
    array.indexOf(value, index + 1) < 0
  )
```

Answer (score 7):

It appears we have lost [Rafael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1961068/519360), which stood as the accepted answer for a few years. This was (at least in 2017) the best-performing solution [if you don't have a mixed-type array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1960473/519360#comment30060330_14438954):

```
Array.prototype.getUnique = function(){
    var u = {}, a = [];
    for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; ++i) {
        if (u.hasOwnProperty(this[i])) {
            continue;
        }
        a.push(this[i]);
        u[this[i]] = 1;
    }
return a;
}
```

If you *do* have a mixed-type array, you can serialize the hash key:

```
Array.prototype.getUnique = function() {
    var hash = {}, result = [], key; 
    for ( var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; ++i ) {
        key = JSON.stringify(this[i]);
        if ( !hash.hasOwnProperty(key) ) {
            hash[key] = true;
            result.push(this[i]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Finding unique Array values in simple method

```
function arrUnique(a){
  var t = [];
  for(var x = 0; x < a.length; x++){
    if(t.indexOf(a[x]) == -1)t.push(a[x]);
  }
  return t;
}
arrUnique([1,4,2,7,1,5,9,2,4,7,2]) // [1, 4, 2, 7, 5, 9]
```

Comment: How can this answer be correct? Expected result for unique array is  [5,9] as per the input given [1,4,2,7,1,5,9,2,4,7,2]

Comment: @PoojaThapa this will extract the unique values from input array.

Answer (score 6):

strange this hasn't been suggested before.. to remove duplicates by object key (`id` below) in an array you can do something like this:

```
const uniqArray = array.filter((obj, idx, arr) => (
  arr.findIndex((o) => o.id === obj.id) === idx
))
```

Comment: Don't both `filter()` and `findIndex()` have to iterate through the array? That would make this a double-loop and therefore twice as expensive to run as any other answer here.

Comment: @AdamKatz yes it will iterate over the array n+1 times. Please be aware that the other answers here using a combination of map, filter, indexOf, reduce etc. also must do this, it's sort of inherent in the problem. To avoid, you could use `new Set()`, or a lookup object similar to the answer by Grozz.

Answer (score 6):

Simple.

```js
return Array.from(new Set(a));
```

Answer (score 5):

For an object-based array with some unique id's, I have a simple solution through which you can sort in linear complexity

```
function getUniqueArr(arr){
    const mapObj = {};
    arr.forEach(a => { 
       mapObj[a.id] = a
    })
    return Object.values(mapObj);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using object keys to make unique array, I have tried following

```
function uniqueArray( ar ) {
  var j = {};

  ar.forEach( function(v) {
    j[v+ '::' + typeof v] = v;
  });


  return Object.keys(j).map(function(v){
    return j[v];
  });
}   

uniqueArray(["1",1,2,3,4,1,"foo", false, false, null,1]);
```

Which returns `["1", 1, 2, 3, 4, "foo", false, null]`

Comment: I think, your answer is the fastest solution because it uses hash.

Answer (score 4):

The task is to get a unique array from an array consisted of **arbitrary types** (primitive and non primitive).

The approach based on using `new Set(...)` is not new. Here it is leveraged by `JSON.stringify(...)`, `JSON.parse(...)` and `[].map` method. The advantages are *universality* (applicability for an array of any types), *short ES6 notation* and probably *performance* for this case:

```js
const dedupExample = [
    { a: 1 },
    { a: 1 },
    [ 1, 2 ],
    [ 1, 2 ],
    1,
    1,
    '1',
    '1'
]

const getUniqArrDeep = arr => {
    const arrStr = arr.map(item => JSON.stringify(item))
    return [...new Set(arrStr)]
        .map(item => JSON.parse(item))
}

console.info(getUniqArrDeep(dedupExample))
   /* [ {a: 1}, [1, 2], 1, '1' ] */
```

Comment: since you're stringifying and then reparsing, positive performance is definitely not an attribute here.

Comment: What do you mean "positive performance" and "attribute here"? Need some elaboration.

Comment: stringifying an object and then parsing it again is one of the most expensive operations you can do in JS apparently. http://jsben.ch/wQ9RU

Comment: @airtonix, It is true, we need to take performance into an account. Some cases are like "Tough times call for tough decisions" though :-)

Answer (score 4):

Finding unique in Array of objects using One Liner

```js
const uniqueBy = (x,f)=>Object.values(x.reduce((a,b)=>((a[f(b)]=b),a),{}));
// f -> should must return string because it will be use as key

const data = [
  { comment: "abc", forItem: 1, inModule: 1 },
  { comment: "abc", forItem: 1, inModule: 1 },
  { comment: "xyz", forItem: 1, inModule: 2 },
  { comment: "xyz", forItem: 1, inModule: 2 },
];

uniqueBy(data, (x) => x.forItem +'-'+ x.inModule); // find unique by item with module
// output
// [
//   { comment: "abc", forItem: 1, inModule: 1 },
//   { comment: "xyz", forItem: 1, inModule: 2 },
// ];

// can also use for strings and number or other primitive values

uniqueBy([1, 2, 2, 1], (v) => v); // [1, 2]
uniqueBy(["a", "b", "a"], (v) => v); // ['a', 'b']

uniqueBy(
  [
    { id: 1, name: "abc" },
    { id: 2, name: "xyz" },
    { id: 1, name: "abc" },
  ],
  (v) => v.id
);
// output
// [
//   { id: 1, name: "abc" },
//   { id: 2, name: "xyz" },
// ];
```

Comment: use can use uniqBy as well instead of uniqueBy

Answer (score 4):

As explained already, `[...new Set(values)]` is the best option, if that's available to you.

Otherwise, here's a one-liner that doesn't iterate the array for every index:

```js
values.sort().filter((val, index, arr) => index === 0 ? true : val !== arr[index - 1]);
```

That simply compares each value to the one before it. The result will be sorted.

Example:

```js
let values = [ 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3 ];
let unique = values.sort().filter((val, index, arr) => index === 0 ? true : val !== arr[index - 1]);
console.log(unique);
```

Comment: Not working when multiple same values are in row

Comment: Added code snippet, seems to work.

Answer (score 3):

Building on other answers, here's another variant that takes an optional flag to choose a strategy (keep first occurrence or keep last):

**Without extending** `Array.prototype`

```
function unique(arr, keepLast) {
  return arr.filter(function (value, index, array) {
    return keepLast ? array.indexOf(value, index + 1) < 0 : array.indexOf(value) === index;
  });
};

// Usage
unique(['a', 1, 2, '1', 1, 3, 2, 6]); // -> ['a', 1, 2, '1', 3, 6]
unique(['a', 1, 2, '1', 1, 3, 2, 6], true); // -> ['a', '1', 1, 3, 2, 6]
```

**Extending** `Array.prototype`

```
Array.prototype.unique = function (keepLast) {
  return this.filter(function (value, index, array) {
    return keepLast ? array.indexOf(value, index + 1) < 0 : array.indexOf(value) === index;
  });
};

// Usage
['a', 1, 2, '1', 1, 3, 2, 6].unique(); // -> ['a', 1, 2, '1', 3, 6]
['a', 1, 2, '1', 1, 3, 2, 6].unique(true); // -> ['a', '1', 1, 3, 2, 6]
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
let ar = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1];
let unique = ar.filter((value, index) => {
        return ar.indexOf(value) == index;
      });
console.log(unique);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Set to eliminate the duplicates.

```
const originalNumbers = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 1, 2, 9];
const uniqueNumbersSet = new Set(originalNumbers);

/** get the array back from the set */
const uniqueNumbersArray = Array.from(uniqueNumbersSet);

/** uniqueNumbersArray outputs to: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9] */
```

Learn more about set: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Comment: JavaScript `Set()` is really a good way to generate unique array

Answer (score 3):

A simple code as this:

```
let arr = [1,'k',12,1,1,'k','12'];
let distictArr=arr.filter((item, index, arr) => arr.indexOf(item) === index);

console.log(distictArr); // [1, 'k', 12, '12']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use jQuery

```
var a = [1,5,1,6,4,5,2,5,4,3,1,2,6,6,3,3,2,4];

// note: jQuery's filter params are opposite of javascript's native implementation :(
var unique = $.makeArray($(a).filter(function(i,itm){ 
    // note: 'index', not 'indexOf'
    return i == $(a).index(itm);
}));

// unique: [1, 5, 6, 4, 2, 3]
```

Originally answered at: [jQuery function to get all unique elements from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381621/jquery-function-to-get-all-unique-elements-from-an-array)

Comment: This one seems only to work for arrays of integers. When I include some strings they all get stripped out of the result.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone using [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/)

```
ko.utils.arrayGetDistinctValues()
```

BTW have look at all `ko.utils.array*` utilities.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this. Jquery provides uniq method:
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/

```
var ids_array = []

$.each($(my_elements), function(index, el) {
    var id = $(this).attr("id")
    ids_array.push(id)
});

var clean_ids_array = jQuery.unique(ids_array)

$.each(clean_ids_array, function(index, id) {
   elment = $("#" + id)   // my uniq element
   // TODO WITH MY ELEMENT
});
```

Comment: If you read the description on the page you linked: Description: Sorts an array of DOM elements, in place, with the duplicates removed. Note that this only works on arrays of DOM elements, not strings or numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Do it with **lodash** and identity lambda function, just define it before use your object

```
const _ = require('lodash');
...    
_.uniqBy([{a:1,b:2},{a:1,b:2},{a:1,b:3}], v=>v.a.toString()+v.b.toString())
_.uniq([1,2,3,3,'a','a','x'])
```

and will have:

```
[{a:1,b:2},{a:1,b:3}]
[1,2,3,'a','x']
```

(this is the simplest way )

Answer (score 2):

Deduplication usually requires an equality operator for the given type. However, using an `eq` function stops us from utilizing a `Set` to determine duplicates in an efficient manner, because `Set` falls back to `===`. As you know for sure, `===` doesn't work for reference types. So we're kind if stuck, right?

The way out is simply using a transformer function that allows us to transform a (reference) type into something we can actually lookup using a `Set`. We could use a hash function, for instance, or `JSON.stringify` the data structure, if it doesn't contain any functions.

Often we only need to access a property, which we can then compare instead of the `Object`'s reference.

Here are two combinators that meet these requirements:

```js
const dedupeOn = k => xs => {
  const s = new Set();

  return xs.filter(o =>
    s.has(o[k])
      ? null
      : (s.add(o[k]), o[k]));
};

const dedupeBy = f => xs => {
  const s = new Set();

  return xs.filter(x => {
    const r = f(x);
    
    return s.has(r)
      ? null
      : (s.add(r), x);
  });
};

const xs = [{foo: "a"}, {foo: "b"}, {foo: "A"}, {foo: "b"}, {foo: "c"}];

console.log(
  dedupeOn("foo") (xs)); // [{foo: "a"}, {foo: "b"}, {foo: "A"}, {foo: "c"}]

console.log(
  dedupeBy(o => o.foo.toLowerCase()) (xs)); // [{foo: "a"}, {foo: "b"}, {foo: "c"}]
```

With these combinators we're extremely flexible in handling all kinds of deduplication issues. It's not the fastes approach, but the most expressive and most generic one.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an almost one-liner that is O(n), keeps the first element, and where you can keep the field you are uniq'ing on separate.

This is a pretty common technique in functional programming - you use `reduce` to build up an array that you return.  Since we build the array like this, we guarantee that we get a stable ordering, unlike the `[...new Set(array)]` approach.  We still use a `Set` to ensure we don't have duplicates, so our accumulator contains both a `Set` and the array we are building.

```js
const removeDuplicates = (arr) =>
  arr.reduce(
    ([set, acc], item) => set.has(item) ? [set, acc] : [set.add(item), (acc.push(item), acc)],
    [new Set(), []]
  )[1]
```

The above will work for simple values, but not for objects, similarly to how `[...new Set(array)]` breaks down.  If the items are objects that contain an `id` property, you'd do:

```js
const removeDuplicates = (arr) =>
  arr.reduce(
    ([set, acc], item) => set.has(item.id) ? [set, acc] : [set.add(item.id), (acc.push(item), acc)],
    [new Set(), []]
  )[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

For removing the duplicates there could be 2 situations.
first, all the data are not objects, secondly all the data are objects.

If all the data are any kind of primitive data type like int, float, string etc then you can follow this one

```
const uniqueArray = [...new Set(oldArray)]
```

But suppose your array consist JS objects like bellow

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'rony',
    email: 'rony@example.com'
}
```

then to get all the unique objects you can follow this

```
let uniqueIds = [];
const uniqueUsers = oldArray.filter(item => {
    if(uniqueIds.includes(item.id)){
        return false;
    }else{
        uniqueIds.push(item.id);
        return true;
    }
})
```

You can also use this method to make any kind of array to make unique. Just keep the tracking key on the `uniqueIds` array.

Answer (score 2):

```js
  var myArray = ["a",2, "a", 2, "b", "1"];
  const uniques = [];
  myArray.forEach((t) => !uniques.includes(t) && uniques.push(t));
  console.log(uniques);
```

Answer (score 2):

Not really a direct literal answer to the original question, because I preferred to have the duplicate values never in the array in the first place. So here's my **UniqueArray**:

```js
class UniqueArray extends Array {
    constructor(...args) {
        super(...new Set(args));
    }
    push(...args) {
        for (const a of args) if (!this.includes(a)) super.push(a);
        return this.length;
    }
    unshift(...args) {
        for (const a of args.reverse()) if (!this.includes(a)) super.unshift(a);
        return this.length;
    }
    concat(...args) {
        var r = new UniqueArray(...this);
        for (const a of args) r.push(...a);
        return r;
    }
}
```

```js
> a = new UniqueArray(1,2,3,1,2,4,5,1)
UniqueArray(5) [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
> a.push(1,4,6)
6
> a
UniqueArray(6) [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
> a.unshift(1)
6
> a
UniqueArray(6) [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
> a.unshift(0)
7
> a
UniqueArray(7) [
  0, 1, 2, 3,
  4, 5, 6
]
> a.concat(2,3,7)
UniqueArray(8) [
  0, 1, 2, 3,
  4, 5, 6, 7
]
```

Answer (score 2):

**Using ES6 (one-liner)**

Array of **Primitive** values

```
let originalArr= ['a', 1, 'a', 2, '1'];

let uniqueArr = [...new Set(originalArr)];
```

Array of **Objects**

```
let uniqueObjArr = [...new Map(originalObjArr.map((item) => [item["propertyName"], item])).values()];

const ObjArray = [
    {
        name: "Eva Devore",
        character: "Evandra",
        episodes: 15,
    },
    {
        name: "Alessia Medina",
        character: "Nixie",
        episodes: 15,
    },
    {
        name: "Kendall Drury",
        character: "DM",
        episodes: 15,
    },
    {
        name: "Thomas Taufan",
        character: "Antrius",
        episodes: 14,
    },
    {
        name: "Alessia Medina",
        character: "Nixie",
        episodes: 15,
    },
];

let uniqueObjArray = [...new Map(ObjArray.map((item) => [item["id"], item])).values()];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [sugar.js:](http://sugarjs.com/)

```
[1,2,2,3,1].unique() // => [1,2,3]

[{id:5, name:"Jay"}, {id:6, name:"Jay"}, {id: 5, name:"Jay"}].unique('id') 
  // => [{id:5, name:"Jay"}, {id:6, name:"Jay"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution for the pile.

I recently needed to make a sorted list unique and I did it using filter that keeps track of the previous item in an object like this:

```
uniqueArray = sortedArray.filter(function(e) { 
    if(e==this.last) 
      return false; 
    this.last=e; return true;  
  },{last:null});
```

Answer (score 1):

The version that accepts selector, should be pretty fast and concise:

```
function unique(xs, f) {
  var seen = {};
  return xs.filter(function(x) {
    var fx = (f && f(x)) || x;
    return !seen[fx] && (seen[fx] = 1);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This one is not pure, it will modify the array, but this is the fastest one. If yours is faster, then please write in the comments ;)

http://jsperf.com/unique-array-webdeb

```
Array.prototype.uniq = function(){
    for(var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; ++i){
        var item = this[i];
        var duplicateIdx = this.indexOf(item, i + 1);
        while(duplicateIdx != -1) {
            this.splice(duplicateIdx, 1);
            duplicateIdx = this.indexOf(item, duplicateIdx);
            l--;
        }
    }

    return this;
}

[
 "",2,4,"A","abc",
 "",2,4,"A","abc",
 "",2,4,"A","abc",
 "",2,4,"A","abc",
 "",2,4,"A","abc",
 "",2,4,"A","abc",
 "",2,4,"A","abc",
 "",2,4,"A","abc"
].uniq() //  ["",2,4,"A","abc"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = [1,4,2,7,1,5,9,2,4,7,2]
var b = {}, c = {};
var len = a.length;
for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
  a[i] in c ? delete b[a[i]] : b[a[i]] = true;
  c[a[i]] = true;
} 

// b contains all unique elements
```

Comment: `b` returns `{5: true, 9: true}` in the example above ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/zLc9av9o/)).

Answer (score 1):

For a array of strings:

```
function removeDuplicatesFromArray(arr) {
  const unique = {};
  arr.forEach((word) => {
    unique[word] = 1; // it doesn't really matter what goes here
  });
  return Object.keys(unique);
}
```

Comment: why is this answer down voted? It does work as expect!

Comment: Thank you. That would also be my approach here as one-liner, with `a` as the array with duplicates and `h` as helper array: `var h = {}; for (var k in a) { h[a[k]] = true;}; var unique = Object.keys(h);` I like using the Object's internal hashtable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Ramda.js](https://ramdajs.com/docs/), a functional javascript library  to do this:

```js
var unique = R.uniq([1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4])
console.log(unique)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

A lot of people have already mentioned using...

```
[...new Set(arr)];
```

And this is a great solution, but my preference is a solution that works with `.filter`. In my opinion filter is a more natural way to get unique values. You're effectively removing duplicates, and removing elements from an array is exactly what filter is meant for. It also lets you chain off of `.map`, `.reduce` and other `.filter` calls. I devised this solution...

```
const unique = () => {
  let cache;  
  return (elem, index, array) => {
    if (!cache) cache = new Set(array);
    return cache.delete(elem);
  };
};

myArray.filter(unique());
```

The caveat is that you need a closure, but I think this is a worthy tradeoff. In terms of performance, it is more performant than the other solutions I have seen posted that use `.filter`, but worse performing than `[...new Set(arr)]`.

See also my github package [youneek](https://github.com/s-taylor/youneek)

Answer (score 1):

**If you want to only get the unique elements and remove the elements which repeats even once, you can do this:**

```js
let array = [2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 8, 1, 1, 2, 9, 3, 5, 3, 4, 8, 4];

function removeDuplicates(inputArray) {
  let output = [];
  let countObject = {};

  for (value of array) {
    countObject[value] = (countObject[value] || 0) + 1;
  }

  for (key in countObject) {
    if (countObject[key] === 1) {
      output.push(key);
    }
  }

  return output;
}

console.log(removeDuplicates(array));
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need .indexOf() at all; you can do this O(n):

```
function SelectDistinct(array) {
    const seenIt = new Set();

    return array.filter(function (val) {
        if (seenIt.has(val)) { 
            return false;
        }

        seenIt.add(val);

        return true;
    });
}

var hasDuplicates = [1,2,3,4,5,5,6,7,7];
console.log(SelectDistinct(hasDuplicates)) //[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

If you don't want to use .filter():

```
function SelectDistinct(array) {
    const seenIt = new Set();
    const distinct = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        const value = array[i];

        if (!seenIt.has(value)) {
            seenIt.add(value);
            distinct.push(value);
        }
    }
    
    return distinct; 
    /* you could also drop the 'distinct' array and return 'Array.from(seenIt)', which converts the set object to an array */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in my solution, I sort data before filtering :

```
const uniqSortedArray = dataArray.sort().filter((v, idx, t) => idx==0 || v != t[idx-1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove duplicates, return the whole objects and want to use ES6 Set and Map syntax, and also run only one loop, you can try this, to get unique ids:

```js
const collection = [{id:3, name: "A"}, {id:3, name: "B"}, {id:4, name: "C"}, {id:5, name: "D"}]

function returnUnique(itemsCollection){
  const itemsMap = new Map();

  itemsCollection.forEach(item => {
    if(itemsMap.size === 0){
      itemsMap.set(item.id, item)       
    }else if(!itemsMap.has(item.id)){
      itemsMap.set(item.id, item)
    }
  });
  
    return [...new Set(itemsMap.values())];
 }

console.log(returnUnique(collection));
```

Answer (score 1):

For an array of tuples, I'll throw things into a Map and let it do the work. With this approach, you have to be mindful about the key you want to be using:

```
const arrayOfArraysWithDuplicates = [
    [1, 'AB'],
    [2, 'CD'],
    [3, 'EF'],
    [1, 'AB'],
    [2, 'CD'],
    [3, 'EF'],
    [3, 'GH'],
]

const uniqueByFirstValue = new Map();
const uniqueBySecondValue = new Map();

arrayOfArraysWithDuplicates.forEach((item) => {
    uniqueByFirstValue.set(item[0], item[1]);
    uniqueBySecondValue.set(item[1], item[0]);
});

let uniqueList = Array.from( uniqueByFirstValue, ( [ value, name ] ) => ( [value, name] ) );

console.log('Unique by first value:');
console.log(uniqueList);

uniqueList = Array.from( uniqueBySecondValue, ( [ value, name ] ) => ( [value, name] ) );

console.log('Unique by second value:');
console.log(uniqueList);
```

Output:

```
Unique by first value:
[ [ 1, 'AB' ], [ 2, 'CD' ], [ 3, 'GH' ] ]

Unique by second value:
[ [ 'AB', 1 ], [ 'CD', 2 ], [ 'EF', 3 ], [ 'GH', 3 ] ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Always remember,
The build-in methods are easy to use. But keep in mind that they have a complexity.

The basic logic is best. There is no hidden complexity.

```
let list = [1, 1, 2, 100, 2] // your array
let check = {}
list = list.filter(item => {
    if(!check[item]) {
        check[item] = true
        return true;
    }
})
```

> or use, let check = [] if you need future traverse to checked items (waste of memory though)

Comment: Maybe filter() was not released at time when this question was asked.

Comment: Does this return the new array without duplicates?

Comment: Yes @coder9833idls

Answer (score 1):

In **ES6/ES2015** and later, you can achieve a succinct one-liner for filtering out duplicate items in an array using the [**Set**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and the [**Spread Operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
let uniqueItems = Array.from(new Set(items));
```

This solution maintains clarity by explicitly converting the Set back into an array using [**Array.from()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from). The end result is an array containing only unique items:

```
[4, 5, 6, 3, 2, 23, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If order is not important then we can make an hash and get the keys to make unique array.

```
var ar = [1,3,4,5,5,6,5,6,2,1];
var uarEle = {};
links.forEach(function(a){ uarEle[a] = 1; });
var uar = keys(uarEle)
```

uar will be having the unique array elements.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at Joeytje50's code on jsperf who has compared a number of alternatives. His code had many minor typos, which made a difference in the performance and the correctness.

More importantly, he is testing on a very small array. I made an array with 1000 integers. Each integer was 100 times a random integer between 0 and 1000. This makes for about 1000/e = 368 duplicates on the average. The results are at [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/unique-in-array/8).

This is a much more realistic scenario of where efficiency might be needed. These changes make dramatic changes in the claims (specifically the code touted as fastest is nowhere near fast). The obvious winners are where hashing techniques are used, with the best one being

```
Array.prototype.getUnique3 = function(){
   var u = Object.create(null), a = [];
   for(var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; ++i){
      if(this[i] in u) continue;
      a.push(this[i]);
      u[this[i]] = 1;
   }
   return a.length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been answered to death already... but...
no one has mentioned the javascript implementation of linq.
Then the `.distinct()` method can be used - and it makes the code super easy to read.

```jsx
var Linq = require('linq-es2015');
var distinctValues =  Linq.asEnumerable(testValues)
            .Select(x)
            .distinct()
            .toArray();
```

```js
var testValues = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 1];

var distinctValues = Enumerable.asEnumerable(testValues)
  .distinct()
  .toArray();

console.log(distinctValues);
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/linq-es5/dist/linq.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array of objects, and you want a `uniqueBy` function, say, by an id field:

```
function uniqueBy(field, arr) {
   return arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
     const exists = acc.find(v => v[field] === curr[field]);
     return exists ? acc : acc.concat(curr);
   }, [])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Making an array of unique arrays, using field[2] as an Id:

```js
const arr = [
  ['497', 'Q0', 'WTX091-B06-138', '0', '1.000000000', 'GROUP001'],
  ['497', 'Q0', 'WTX091-B09-92', '1', '0.866899288', 'GROUP001'],
  ['497', 'Q0', 'WTX091-B09-92', '2', '0.846036819', 'GROUP001'],
  ['497', 'Q0', 'WTX091-B09-57', '3', '0.835025326', 'GROUP001'],
  ['497', 'Q0', 'WTX091-B43-79', '4', '0.765068215', 'GROUP001'],
  ['497', 'Q0', 'WTX091-B43-56', '5', '0.764211464', 'GROUP001'],
  ['497', 'Q0', 'WTX091-B44-448', '6', '0.761701704', 'GROUP001'],
  ['497', 'Q0', 'WTX091-B44-12', '7', '0.761701704', 'GROUP001'],
  ['497', 'Q0', 'WTX091-B49-128', '8', '0.747434800', 'GROUP001'],
  ['497', 'Q0', 'WTX091-B18-17', '9', '0.746724770', 'GROUP001'],
  ['497', 'Q0', 'WTX091-B19-374', '10', '0.733379549', 'GROUP001'],
  ['497', 'Q0', 'WTX091-B19-344', '11', '0.731421782', 'GROUP001'],
  ['497', 'Q0', 'WTX091-B09-92', '12', '0.726450470', 'GROUP001'],
  ['497', 'Q0', 'WTX091-B19-174', '13', '0.712757036', 'GROUP001']
];


arr.filter((val1, idx1, arr) => !!~val1.indexOf(val1[2]) &&
  !(arr.filter((val2, idx2) => !!~val2.indexOf(val1[2]) &&
    idx2 < idx1).length));

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an ES6 function which removes duplicates from an array of objects, filtering by the specified object property

```
function dedupe(arr = [], fnCheck = _ => _) {
  const set = new Set();
  let len = arr.length;

  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    const primitive = fnCheck(arr[i]);
    if (set.has(primitive)) {
      // duplicate, cut it
      arr.splice(i, 1);
      i--;
      len--;
    } else {
      // new item, add it
      set.add(primitive);
    }
  }

  return arr;
}

const test = [
    {video:{slug: "a"}},
    {video:{slug: "a"}},
    {video:{slug: "b"}},
    {video:{slug: "c"}},
    {video:{slug: "c"}}
]
console.log(dedupe(test, x => x.video.slug));

// [{video:{slug: "a"}}, {video:{slug: "b"}}, {video:{slug: "c"}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that uses es6 reduce and find array helper methods to remove duplicates.

```js
let numbers = [2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6, 6];

const removeDups = array => {
  return array.reduce((acc, inc) => {
    if (!acc.find(i => i === inc)) {
      acc.push(inc);
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
}

console.log(removeDups(numbers)); /// [2,3,5,6]
```

Answer (score 0):

The Object answer above does not seem to work for me in my use case with Objects.

I have modified it as follows:

```
var j = {};

this.forEach( function(v) {
   var typ = typeof v;
   var v = (typ === 'object') ? JSON.stringify(v) : v;

   j[v + '::' + typ] = v;
});

return Object.keys(j).map(function(v){
  if ( v.indexOf('::object') > -1 ) {
    return JSON.parse(j[v]);
  }

  return j[v];
});
```

This seems to now work correctly for objects, arrays, arrays with mixed values, booleans, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var numbers = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4];

function unique(dupArray) {
  return dupArray.reduce(function(previous, num) {

    if (previous.find(function(item) {
        return item == num;
      })) {
      return previous;
    } else {
      previous.push(num);
      return previous;
    }
  }, [])
}

var check = unique(numbers);
console.log(check);
```

Answer (score 0):

To filter-out undefined and null values because most of the time you do not need them.

```
const uniques = myArray.filter(e => e).filter((e, i, a) => a.indexOf(e) === i);
```

or

```
const uniques = [...new Set(myArray.filter(e => e))];
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I need to get unique occurrences from an array of objects. Lodash seems like a nice helper but I don't think filtering an array justifies adding a dependency to a project.

Let's assume the comparison of two objects poses on comparing a property, an id for example.

`const a = [{id: 3}, {id: 4}, {id: 3}, {id: 5}, {id: 5}, {id: 5}];`

Since we all love one line snippets, here is how it can be done:

`a.reduce((acc, curr) => acc.find(e => e.id === curr.id) ? acc : [...acc, curr], [])`

Answer (score 0):

This solution should be very fast, and will work in many cases.

1. Convert the indexed array items to object keys
2. Use Object.keys function

   ```
   var indexArray = ["hi","welcome","welcome",1,-9];
   var keyArray = {};
   indexArray.forEach(function(item){ keyArray[item]=null; });
   var uniqueArray = Object.keys(keyArray);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple example where we can remove objects from array having repeated id in objects,

```
  let data = new Array({id: 1},{id: 2},{id: 3},{id: 1},{id: 3});
  let unique = [];
  let tempArr = [];
  console.log('before', data);
  data.forEach((value, index) => {
    if (unique.indexOf(value.id) === -1) {
      unique.push(value.id);
    } else {
      tempArr.push(index);    
    }
  });
  tempArr.reverse();
  tempArr.forEach(ele => {
    data.splice(ele, 1);
  });
  console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to transform values into strings to filter also nested objects values.

```
const uniq = (arg = []) => {
  const stringifyedArg = arg.map(value => JSON.stringify(value))
  return arg.filter((value, index, self) => {
    if (typeof value === 'object')
      return stringifyedArg.indexOf(JSON.stringify(value)) === index
    return self.indexOf(value) === index
  })
}

    console.log(uniq([21, 'twenty one', 21])) // [21, 'twenty one']
    console.log(uniq([{ a: 21 }, { a: 'twenty one' }, { a: 21 }])) // [{a: 21}, {a: 'twenty one'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

For my part this was the easiest solution

```js
// A way to check if the arrays are equal
const a = ['A', 'B', 'C'].sort().toString()
const b = ['A', 'C', 'B'].sort().toString()

console.log(a === b); // true


// Test Case
const data = [
  { group: 'A', name: 'SD' },
  { group: 'B', name: 'FI' },
  { group: 'A', name: 'SD' },
  { group: 'B', name: 'CO' }
];

// Return a new Array without dublocates
function unique(data) {
  return data.reduce(function (accumulator, currentValue) {
    // Convert to string in order to check if they are the same value.
    const currentKeys = Object.keys(currentValue).sort().toString();
    const currentValues = Object.values(currentValue).sort().toString();

    let hasObject = false
    
    for (const obj of accumulator) {
      // Convert keys and values into strings so we can
      // see if they are equal with the currentValue
      const keys = Object.keys(obj).sort().toString();
      const values = Object.values(obj).sort().toString();
      // Check if keys and values are equal
      if (keys === currentKeys && values === currentValues) {
        hasObject = true
      }
    }

    // Push the object if it does not exist already.
    if (!hasObject) {
      accumulator.push(currentValue)
    }

    return accumulator
  }, []);
}

// Run Test Case
console.log(unique(data)); // [ { group: 'A', name: 'SD' }, { group: 'B', name: 'FI' }, { group: 'B', name: 'CO' } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach using comparators (I care more about clean code than performance):

```js
const list = [
    {name: "Meier"},
    {name: "Hans"},
    {name: "Meier"},
]
const compare = (a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
const uniqueNames = list.makeUnique(compare);
uniqueNames.pushIfAbsent({name: "Hans"}, compare);
```

Prototype declaration:

```js
declare global {
    interface Array<T>  {
        pushIfAbsent(item: T, compare:(a:T, b:T)=>number): number;
    }
    interface Array<T>  {
        makeUnique(compare:(a:T, b:T)=>number): Array<T>;
    }
}
Array.prototype.pushIfAbsent = function <T>(this:T[], item:T, compare:(a:T, b:T)=>number) {
    if (!this.find(existing => compare(existing, item)===0)) {
        return this.push(item)
    } else {
        return this.length;
    }
}
Array.prototype.makeUnique = function <T>(this:T[], compare:(a:T, b:T)=>number) {
    return this.filter((existing, index, self) => self.findIndex(item => compare(existing, item) == 0) == index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A modern approach that's extensible, fast, efficient and easy to read, using [iter-ops](https://github.com/vitaly-t/iter-ops) library:

```
import {pipe, distinct} from 'iter-ops';

const input = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]; // our data

const i = pipe(input, distinct()); // distinct iterable

console.log([...i]); //=> [1, 2, 3]
```

And if your input is an array of objects, you will just provide a key selector for the `distinct` operator.

Answer (score 0):

There's already bunch of great answers. Here's my approach.

```
var removeDuplicates = function(nums) {
    let filteredArr = [];
    nums.forEach((item) => {
        if(!filteredArr.includes(item)) {
            filteredArr.push(item);
        }
    })

  return filteredArr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ES2016 .includes() One Method Simple Answer:

```
var arr = [1,5,2,4,1,6]
function getOrigs(arr) {
  let unique = []
  arr && arr.forEach(number => {
    !unique.includes(number) && unique.push(number)
    if (number === arr[arr.length - 1]) {
      console.log('unique: ', unique)
    }
  })
}
getOrigs(arr)
```

Use this instead:

- later ES version
- Simple question shouldn't use multiple advanced JS methods and push(), length() and forEach() are common
- Easier readability utilizing a closure
- Seems better on memory, garbage collection, and performance than the others
- Less lines of code: if you separated lines based on where there is a line ending, you would only need one line of logic (so you can call or refactor this one-liner however you want):

```
var arr = [1,5,2,4,1,6];
function getOrigs(arr) {let unique = []; 
  arr && arr.forEach(number => !unique.includes(number) && unique.push(number) && ((number === arr[arr.length - 1]) && console.log('unique: ', unique)))};
getOrigs(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```js
let d_array = [1, 2, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'];
d_array = d_array.filter((x,i)=>d_array.indexOf(x)===i);
console.log(d_array); // [1, 2, 3, "a", "b", "c"]
```

This loops through the array, checks if the first found result of the same entry in the array is the current index, and if so, allows it to be in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to remove duplicates from an array of objects. Duplicates had the same ids. Here is what I did.

```js
// prev data
const prev = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "foo",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "baz",
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "foo",
  },
];

// method:
// Step 1: put them in an object with the id as the key. Value of same id would get overriden.
// Step 2: get all the values.

const tempObj = {};
prev.forEach((n) => (tempObj[n.id] = n));
const next = Object.values(tempObj);

// result
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "foo",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "baz",
  }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simple**

```js
const listWithDupes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9];

const uniqueList = Object.values(listWithDupes.reduce((acc, next) => ({ ...acc,
  [next]: next
}), {}));

console.log(uniqueList);
```

Answer (score 0):

An old way With 2 Loops.

```
let a = ["Messi", 23, false, 11, 17, true, 23, "Messi", "Sachin", "2023", true, "Sachin"];

let b = [];
    for (let i in a) {
        let found = false;
        for (let j in b) {
            if (a[i] === b[j]) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (found === false) {
            b.push(a[i]);
        }
    }

console.log(b); //['Messi', 23, false, 11, 17, true, 'Sachin', '2023']
```

Answer (score -1):

Yet another answer, just because I wrote one for my specific use case.  I happened to be sorting the array anyway, and given I'm sorting I can use that to deduplicate.

Note that my sort deals with my specific data types, you might need a different sort depending on what sort of elements you have.

```
var sortAndDedup = function(array) {
  array.sort(function(a,b){
    if(isNaN(a) && isNaN(b)) { return a > b ? 1 : (a < b ? -1 : 0); }
    if(isNaN(a)) { return 1; }
    if(isNaN(b)) { return -1; }
    return a-b;
  });

  var newArray = [];
  var len = array.length;
  for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
    if(i === 0 || array[i] != array[i-1]){
      newArray.push(array[i]);
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

This script modify the array, filtering out duplicated values. It works with numbers and strings.

https://jsfiddle.net/qsdL6y5j/1/

```
    Array.prototype.getUnique = function () {
        var unique = this.filter(function (elem, pos) {
            return this.indexOf(elem) == pos;
        }.bind(this));
        this.length = 0;
        this.splice(0, 0, unique);
    }

    var duplicates = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 0, 4, 4];
    duplicates.getUnique();
    alert(duplicates);
```

---

This version instead, allow you to return a new array with unique value keeping the original (just pass true).

https://jsfiddle.net/dj7qxyL7/

```
    Array.prototype.getUnique = function (createArray) {
        createArray = createArray === true ? true : false;
        var temp = JSON.stringify(this);
        temp = JSON.parse(temp);
        if (createArray) {
            var unique = temp.filter(function (elem, pos) {
                return temp.indexOf(elem) == pos;
            }.bind(this));
            return unique;
        }
        else {
            var unique = this.filter(function (elem, pos) {
                return this.indexOf(elem) == pos;
            }.bind(this));
            this.length = 0;
            this.splice(0, 0, unique);
        }
    }

    var duplicates = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 0, 4, 4];
    console.log('++++ ovveride')
    duplicates.getUnique();
    console.log(duplicates);
    console.log('++++ new array')
    var duplicates2 = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 0, 4, 4];
    var unique = duplicates2.getUnique(true);
    console.log(unique);
    console.log('++++ original')
    console.log(duplicates2);
```

---

```
Browser support:

Feature Chrome  Firefox (Gecko)     Internet Explorer   Opera   Safari
Basic support   (Yes)   1.5 (1.8)   9                   (Yes)   (Yes)
```

Comment: In the first comment why did you add `this.length = 0;` and `this.splice(0, 0, unique);`?

Also would this not be enough?
`Array.prototype.uniques = function() {
        return this.filter(function(value, index){
            return this.indexOf(value) === index;
        }.bind(this));
    };`

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
function removeDuplicates(arr){
  var temp = arr.sort();
  for(i = 0; i < temp.length; i++){
    if(temp[i] == temp[i + 1]){
      temp.splice(i,1);
      i--;
    }
  }
  return temp;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Using **mongoose** I had an array of **ObjectIds** to work with.

I had a array/list of Object Ids to work with which first needed to be set to an string and after the unique set, amended back to Object Ids.

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose')

var ids = [ObjectId("1"), ObjectId("2"), ObjectId("3")]

var toStringIds = ids.map(e => '' + e)
let uniqueIds = [...new Set(toStringIds)]
uniqueIds = uniqueIds.map(b => mongoose.Types.ObjectId(b))


console.log("uniqueIds :", uniqueIds)
```

Answer (score -1):

let arr = [1,5,1,2,2,1,3,2,3,3,3,1,10]

for(let i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {

```
for(let j = i+1; j<arr.length;j++) {

    if(arr[i] === arr[j]) {
        arr[j] = 0;
    }
    
}
if(arr[i] === 0) {
   
  arr.splice(i,1)
  i--
```

}

}

console.log(arr)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.

Answer (score -2):

```js
(function() {
    "use strict";

    Array.prototype.unique = function unique() {
        var self = this;
        return self.filter(function(a) {
            var that = this;
            // console.log(that);
            return !that[a] ? that[a] = true : false;
        }, {});
    }

    var sampleArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
    var distinctArray = sampleArray.unique();
    console.log(distinctArray);
})();
```

```html
Here is the simple way to solve this problem...
```

Answer (score -2):

Short and sweet prototype solution:

```js
Array.prototype.unique = function() {
  return [...new Set(this)]
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I would sort the array, then all duplicates are neighbours.
Then walk once through the array and eliminate all duplicates.

```
function getUniques(array) {
  var l = array.length
  if(l > 1) {
    // get a cloned copy and sort it
    array = [...array].sort();
    var i = 1, j = 0;
    while(i < l) {
      if(array[i] != array[j]) {
        array[++j] = array[i];
      }
      i++;
    }
    array.length = j + 1;
  }
  return array;
}
```