# Can a List of String be told to check for duplicates?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Does a List have a property or mechanism by which I can prevent duplicate entries from being added to it, or do I have to search the list for it each time?

IOW, it would be much nicer just to go:

```
List<String> AAppsToDisplay = new List<String>();
AAppsToDisplay.DuplicatesAllowed = false;
...
while (odr.Read()) 
{
  AAppsToDisplay.Add(odr.GetString(0)); 
}
```

than to have to do this:

```
List<String> AAppsToDisplay = new List<String>();
. . .
String s = String.Empty;
while (odr.Read()) 
{
  s = odr.GetString(0);
  if (! AAppsToDisplay.Contains(s))
  {
    AAppsToDisplay.Add(s);  
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you require both *ordering* and being *free of duplicates*?

Comment: Here you go Clay: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918742/efficient-list-of-unique-strings-c-sharp   none the less I'd still be interested in Eric's advice

Comment: Just clarifying Eric's comment: ordering refers to items being stored in the order they were added, rather than a (basically) arbitrary order. If you do not need the list to be ordered, use a `HashSet<T>`.

Comment: @Eric: no, ordering doesn't matter to me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use a more appropriate tool for the job instead, `HashSet<string>`.

```
var hashset = new HashSet<string>();

// in loop
hashset.Add(value);
```

If you were to use `Contains` on the HashSet, it would be a more optimal solution than using it on `List<string>`, particularly if the set grew particularly large. However, if it is permissible within your business requirement to silently discard duplicates, then you do not need to. The `Add` method returns a boolean indicating if the value was added. Duplicates never make it into the set.

---

It is important to note that `HashSet<T>` is not documented to preserve insertion order. You *may* observe results in the same order of insertion, and that may be impacted by your particular usage, but you should not rely upon it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an extension method to the List class:

```
public static class StringListExtensions {
    public static bool AddIfNotPresent(this List<string> list, string newString) {
        if (!list.Contains(newString)) {
            this.Add(newString);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you like the HashSet?

Comment: I know the HashSet is better, however the extension could suit if you have used this class in many places, or it's in a third party dll etc.

Comment: It's amazing how many different ways there are to skin a cat, but now I'm hungry for corned beef hash.

Answer (score 1):

You could use System.Linq library and go

```
List<String> AAppsToDisplay = new List<String>();
...
while (odr.Read()) 
{
  AAppsToDisplay.Add(odr.GetString(0)); 
}

//new code
AAppsToDisplay = AAppsToDisplay.Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: I have never heard of it, just copied and pasted from above sorry - have removed it